# Is there a way to get docky to launch a new instance?

Tags: linux, gnome, gnome-do, docky

So i'm really loving the whole gnome-do/docky thing. My question is that on other docks, you can hold down a modifier key to launch a new instance rather then switching to an already opened instance of an app. So lets say I have chrome on the win7 dock

- first click launches chrome
- other clicks will focus the opened window
- shift click will open a new instance of chrome
- ctrl-shift-click will launch a new instance as admin

is there anything similar in docky?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they don't have such feature yet. But you can always do right-click and select "new window".

Note, that docky is currently splitting out of gnome-do, the version included in gnome-do actually is not supported anymore and no one is working on it. You might be better off installing separate version, although that one doesn't have feature in question either.

Comment: well thanks anyways, probably just a matter of time though

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is something new but I just noticed that clicking the third button (wheel on the mouse) actually opens new instance. I'm running standalone docky from [docky-core ppa](https://launchpad.net/~docky-core/+archive/ppa).

Comment: thank you, worked for me! (clicking both left and right touchpad buttons = third mouse button)